# Рамка на bash с использованием символов из Unicode Box Drawing

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Захотелось мне как-то оформить башевский скрипт, чтобы выдавал менюшку в красивой рамочке. Погуглил, почесал репу, ну и накатал пару небольших функций. Результатом, с удовольствием, делюсь с участниками SO, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: с помощью `whiptail | dialog` это не реализуемо?

Comment: Я исходил из того, чтобы работало без установки доп пакетов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот что получилось:

```
declare -A C # Массив значений цветов
def_colors ()
{
    C[Black]='\e[30m'
    C[Red]='\e[31m'
    C[Green]='\e[32m'
    C[Yellow]='\e[33m'
    C[Blue]='\e[34m'
    C[Magenta]='\e[35m'
    C[Cyan]='\e[36m'
    C[LGray]='\e[37m'

    C[Default]='\e[39m'

    C[DGray]='\e[90m'
    C[LRed]='\e[91m'
    C[LGreen]='\e[92m'
    C[LYellow]='\e[93m'
    C[LBlue]='\e[94m'
    C[LMagenta]='\e[95m'
    C[LCyan]='\e[96m'
    C[White]='\e[97m'

    C[Normal]='\e[0m'
}

draw_line ()
{
    local position="$1"
    local width_line="$2"
    local repeat="$4"
    local left_position="$3"
    local line_simbol='\u2501'
    local line left_indent spacer

    [[ $width_line -ne 0 ]] && spacer="\e[${width_line}C"
    [[ $left_position -ne 0 ]] && left_indent="\e[${left_position}C"

    case "$position" in
        --top)
            left_corner='\u250F'
            right_corner='\u2513'
            ;;
        --bottom)
            left_corner='\u2517'
            right_corner='\u251B'
            ;;
        --blank)
            left_corner='\u2503'
            right_corner='\u2503'
            ;;
        --box-separator)
            left_corner="\u2523"
            right_corner="\u252B"
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$position" == '--blank' ]]; then
        while read -r;do
            line+="${left_indent}${left_corner}${spacer}${right_corner}\n"
        done < <(seq "$repeat")
        printf '%b' "$line"
    else
        while read -r;do
            line+="$line_simbol"
        done < <(seq "$width_line")
        printf '%b%b%b%b\n' "${left_indent}" "$left_corner" "$line" "$right_corner"
    fi
}

draw_frame ()
{

    local footer_height frame_color frame_height frame_width
    local top_position left_position restore_position start_write

    local terminal_width
        terminal_width=$(tput cols)
    local terminal_hight
        terminal_hight=$(tput lines)

    until [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; do
        case "$1" in
            -t) if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
                    if [[ "$2" -lt "$(( terminal_hight - 5 ))" ]];then
                        top_position="$2"
                    else
                        top_position="$(( terminal_hight - 5 ))"
                    fi
                    shift
                else
                    if [[ -z "$2" ]]; then
                        top_position=0
                    else
                        echo 'Set a positive numeric value for the top position of frame'
                    fi
                fi
                ;;
            -l) if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
                    if [[ "$2" -lt "$(( terminal_width - 2 ))" ]];then
                        left_position="$2"
                    else
                        left_position="$(( terminal_width - 2 ))"
                    fi
                    shift
                else
                    if [[ -z "$2" ]]; then
                        left_position=0
                    else
                        echo 'Set a positive numeric value for the left position of frame'
                    fi
                fi
                ;;
            -w) if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
                    if [[ "$2" -lt "$(( terminal_width - 2 ))" ]];then
                        frame_width="$2"
                    else
                        frame_width="$(( terminal_width - 2 ))"
                    fi
                    shift
                else
                    echo 'Set a positive numeric value for the frame width'
                    tput cnorm
                    return 1
                fi
                ;;
            -h) if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
                    if [[ "$2" -lt "$(( terminal_hight - 5 ))" ]];then
                        frame_height="$2"
                    else
                        frame_height="$(( terminal_hight - 5 ))"
                    fi
                    shift
                else
                    echo 'Set a positive numeric value for the frame height'
                    tput cnorm
                    return 1
                fi
                ;;
            -c) if [[ "$2" =~ \\e\[[0-9]{1,2}m$ ]]; then
                    frame_color="$2"
                    shift
                else
                    [[ "$2" ]] &&
                    {
                        [[ "$2" =~ ^- ]] || shift
                    }
                fi
                ;;
            -f) if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]];then
                    footer_height="$2"
                    shift
                else
                    [[ "$2" ]] &&
                    {
                        [[ "$2" =~ ^- ]] || shift
                    }
                    footer_height=1
                fi
                ;;
            -r|--restore-position)
                restore_position='1'
                ;;
            -s|--start-write)
                start_write='1'
                ;;
        esac
        shift
    done

    top_position=${top_position:-0}
    left_position=${left_position:-0}

    [[ "$start_write" ]] && restore_position=
    [[ "${restore_position:-0}" -eq 1 ]] && tput sc # Сохраняем позицию курсора

    tput civis
    clear

    tput cup "$top_position" 0
    if [[ $(( frame_width + left_position )) -gt $(( terminal_width - 2 )) ]];then
        frame_width=$(( terminal_width - left_position - 2 ))
    fi
    if [[ $(( frame_height + top_position )) -gt $(( terminal_hight - 5 )) ]];then
        frame_height=$(( terminal_hight - top_position - 5 ))
    fi

    [[ "$frame_color" ]] && printf '%b' "$frame_color"
    if [[ "$frame_width" ]] && [[ "$frame_height" ]]; then
        draw_line --top "$frame_width" "$left_position"
        draw_line --blank "$frame_width" "$left_position" "$frame_height"
        [[ -n "$footer_height" ]] && \
            draw_line --box-separator "$frame_width" "$left_position" && \
                draw_line --blank "$frame_width" "$left_position" "$footer_height"
        draw_line --bottom "$frame_width" "$left_position"
    fi
    [[ "$frame_color" ]] && printf '%b' '\e[0m'

    [[ "${restore_position:-0}" -eq 1 ]] && {
            tput rc # Восстановить позицию

            }

    [[ "$footer_height" ]] && (( footer_height++ ))
    [[ "${start_write:-0}" -eq 1 ]] && \
        printf '%b' \
            "\\e[$(( frame_height + 1 + ${footer_height:-0} ))A\\e[$(( left_position + 1 ))C"

    tput cnorm
}
```

> -w    Ширина рамки;
>   -h    Высота рамки без учета футера;
>   -c    Цвет рамки;
>   -f    Высота футера;
>
> Высота и ширина - это количества строк и символов, соответственно, которые можно вписать не зацепив саму рамку
>
> Если опустить -f, то просто будет бокс без футера
>   Если опустить -с, то цвет рамки будет стандартным для вашего терминала

```
draw_frame -w 50 -h 20 -c ${C[Green]} -t 5 -l 5 -f 1
```

Все размеры в колонках и линиях терминала соответственно.

**UPD**
Немного доработал, теперь можно задавать позицию бокса относительно левого верхнего угла терминала:

> -l сдвиг влево
>   -t сдвиг вниз

Плюс. Добавил две опции:

> -r [--restore-position] - Возвращает курсор туда, где он находился до начала отрисовки
>   -s [--start-write] - Устанавливает курсор в левый верхний угол пустого поля фрейма

[image: bash unicode drawing box]